# Windows Explorer restarts everytime I open download folder

Tags: windows-7

My computer has been runnning slow for a while, then every time I open downloads folder Windows explorer restarts. I installed regzooka to clean up my computer and have run virus and spyware checks but nothing has changed

Comment: is it windows xp? windows 7?  try running combofix and see if you are also infected:   http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/

Comment: Please don't recommend ComboFix without trying basic troubleshooting tools first.

Comment: Do you have any video files in the Downloads folder at all?

Comment: Did this happen before or after running regzooka?

Comment: yes i have video files in the foder, I tried moving them to another folder then it happened again, I'm using windows & and it happened before I tried regzooka.....your help is appreciated  thanks